# How to make Javascript calss/constructor callable on HTMLCollection or Element

Tags: javascript

I have a JS constructor/class named `slider`

What I want to be able to do is call the slidor as a function of an HTMLCollection or a Element.

I want to make calls like

`document.getElementsByClassName('my-class').slider()`

How do I do it? Was not able to google it out, maybe because I do not know the term for this type of implementation

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @vlaz I want to develop  a  JS plugin like slick slider : https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick

Comment: You can make a method that creates an instance by `new`ing the constructor, but no you cannot put a class/constructor directly on the element (collection). And you absolutely shouldn't do that anyway. Pass the element (collection) to the constructor as an argument instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 HTMLCollection.prototype.slider = function() {
   //...
 }
```

This is called "extending native prototypes" and is generally a bad practice. Do you really need that? Why not just:

```
function slider(nodes) { /*...*/ }

slider(document.getElementsByClassName("whatever"));
```

Or just:

```
function slider(selector) {
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  //...
}

slider(".someclass");
```

Comment: Note very good idea to extend prototype without checking if property already defined.

Comment: Thanks, Jonas! Popular plugins follow this pattern, like this one: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick

Comment: @hack4mer "popular" != "well-written"

Comment: I would say that it is never a good idea even if you do the check.

Comment: @JonasW. is right. The better way is not to pollute prototypes at all. Take a look how jQuery plugins defined and works

Comment: @hack4mer and as far as i can see this plugin does not extend native prototypes.

Comment: Jonas, I have seen multiple jQuery plugins to follow this pattern. Any reason that they do it?

Comment: @hack4mer bad programmers?

Comment: Yes this plugin is not extending native prototype, yet their APIs can be called in the manner I desire. How?

Comment: @hack4mer no they can't. They can be called on a jquery object, which is an entire different thing.

Comment: They don't call `element.slick()`, they call `$(element).slick()` - the `$()` wraps the element in a jQuery object. jQuery itself has support for libraries to hook themselves to it and add custom stuff like `.slick()` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, great info. any idea how can I do that then? will be grateful.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ - you can also see how slick does - it's the very last thing in `slick.js` on GitHub. Essentially, you make your library independently and then add a new function to `$.fn` - e.g., `$.fn.myLibrary = /* ... */`